# IndexError: list index out of range while connecting to SFTP server using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysftp

i wrote a python script to connect to SFTP server using public key authentication. Code gets it server credentials from another text file called "config file" which is of format:

IP,USERNAME

IP2,USERNAME2

when the config file contains more than 5 IP's and usernames it throws the error(see below). although it does not affect the output but whats the reason of the error and how to solve it or is there any better way to do it

My Code:

```
import os
import pysftp
import socket
import paramiko
import time
import os.path
import shutil
import pysftp
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from stat import S_IMODE, S_ISDIR, S_ISREG

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys=None

import os

privatekeyfile = os.path.expanduser("C:\\Users\\Rohan\\.ssh\\cool.prv")
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile)


config_file_path = "config15.txt"     
file = open(config_file_path, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
all_rows = [row for row in reader]
for line in all_rows:
    server_ip = line[0]
    username = line[1]
    with pysftp.Connection(host=server_ip, username=username, private_key=mykey, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        r = (socket.gethostbyaddr(server_ip))
        print("connection successful with ", r)
```

Output and Error:(if there are 10 IP's in the config file)

```
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rohan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/m.py", line 30, in <module>
    server_ip = line[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
connection successful with  ('lootera', [], ['127.0.0.1'])
```

Comment: `print(line)` right before that, what do you get…? You probably have a blank line in your file.

Comment: @deceze   No blank line in config file. I recheked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't know the config file, we can't tell if there is a mistake in there. However you can just check if a line contains two values. This way you avoid `IndexError`:

```
for line in all_rows:
    if len(line) != 2:
        continue
    server_ip = line[0]
    username = line[1]
```

Also:

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
all_rows = [row for row in reader]
for line in all_rows:
```

Is fairly inefficient. Why not shorten it?

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
for line in reader:
```